# Unknown Error When Uploading File with AjaxFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, file-upload

I have several pages which upload pictures to my web app.  Everything was working perfectly on production and development.  Then one day it just stopped.  I have gone over everything I can think of but can't get it to work.  It never gets to the server side UploadComplete.  All I get is the red line 2.51 MB (error).

Please let me know what other information you need.  I can provide code samples, web.config, etc.  I have tried playing with security permissions with no luck.  I have cleared C:\Windows\Temp and tried uploading images.  It creates a directory called _AjaxFileUpload, but doesn't put the image there.

As I said before, this was working fine in production and development.  I'm guessing an issue with the temp directory but not really sure where the problem is.

Comment: What directory are you uploading the file to?

Comment: After more research I found that the error happens in the JS code that is part of the ajaxfileupload control.  Specifically, the Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control.prototype.doneAndUploadNextFile is called.  In this process the XMLHTTPRequest (a) calls open (a.open) and returns with a readystate of 1 and status of 0.  The function then sets an event a.onreadystatechange which resultes in a ready state of 2, 3 and 4, each with a status of 500.

Comment: Sorry mason, I just noticed your post.  I'm not getting the UploadComplete event so I'm not uploading to a specific directory.  I have noticed that in VS debug it appears to be useing the current user temp directory and after publishing it is using the Windows\Temp directory.  I have given Everyone full permissions to these two directories.

Comment: Continuing to trouble shoot I found that the first error is actually generated in the Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control.prototype.upload event.

Comment: Still looking, finally found this error:   "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\shawnrailey\AppData\Local\Temp\17533\_AjaxFileUpload\5B1DC315-5AFB-1A0C-AA43-91A6E0E45B4F'".  I checked and the user group Everyone has full access to Temp and 17533.

Comment: By default, web applications can write data to the App_Data folder. Try setting that as the upload location. You may need to add that folder to the root of your site if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I haven't found anywhere to set the default folder for the client side.  Just to be clear, you are suggesting I create a virtual folder in my project and point it to the temp folder?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that at all. Add a folder to your root folder, called App-Data. Then set ~/App_Data as the upload location. For more info, see [A Beginner's Guide to ASP.NET Application Folders](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders).

Comment: Thanks mason.  I already have a folder called App_Data in my project.  The folder I was using to store pictures is still working to save PDF files that are dynamically created.  The problem is how do I set the default folder for an ajaxfileupload control?  It fails on the client side before I ever get the ability to save the image to the production folder on the server.

Comment: FYI, not an answer, but I've submitted the "red error of death" complaint to DevExpress over on GitHub and referenced your question: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/573